# XPath based on id attribute value that starts with something?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

For example if I have multiple anchor elements on a site and the easiest way to get them is via their ID, but the IDs look like this:

```
lots of html...
    <a href="google.com" id="foo_1">hop1</a>
...lots of html...
    <a href="yahoo.com" id="foo_2">hop2</a>
...lots of html...
    <a href="stackoverflow.com" id="foo_1003">hop3</a>
...lots of html
```

Is it possible to select the `href` attributes of all anchor elements whose `id` has the `"foo_"` part of the `id`? In other words, can I add a wildcard in an attribute's value in XPath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XPath expression, which works with all versions of XPath,

```
//a[starts-with(@id,"foo_")]/@href
```

will select all `a/@href` attributes whose `a` has an `id` attribute value that starts with `"foo_"`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use matches function in terms of XSL:

1. Starting with foo_    `//a/@id[matches(.,'^foo_\d+')]`
2. Containing foo_    `//a/@id[matches(.,'foo_\d+')]`

Please specify for which language you are asking for

Comment: I'm using C# and HTML Agility Pack. Thanks I'll try this right now.

Comment: The matches() function in XPath requires XPath 2.0, not sure that's available in HTML Agility Pack?

Comment: Okey I rewrote it a bit to try and directly get the href's. Like so: @"//a[@id[matches(.,'thread_title_\d+')]]/@href". However it doesn't seem to work. I expect I'm misunderstanding what the . would be in this case. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Can you show input where is the @href which matches 'thread_title' in given input it is not present.

Comment: Oops!! Sorry its my mistake. My XPath is returning '@id' but we need '@href'.